# call serverside script upon textbox value change

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I know I'm doing it wrong, not sure how to proceed. Please help. If there is any other way!

I've a `Textbox`, which is loaded using `JQuery`. Once the textbox value is changed, I need to call the server side script which is defined in `OnTextChanged`

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Textbox1"  OnTextChanged="Textbox1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

In JQuery, I've assigning the value. I've a `Textbox` and a `button`. On click of this button, I open a window with `TreeView`. Once the value is selected from `TreeView`, I need to populate in Textbox AND I need to refresh few `Server controls`. This is where I needed `Textbox1_TextChanged` Server call

```
 $('#Textbox1').val("TreeView Selected Value");
```

Once this value is assigned, I need to call `Textbox1_TextChanged` event to be called. The server side method is not being called after I change the textbox value!

**Solution:**

Here is a good article on how to implement the post back from JavaScript.  http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/217965-calling-c%23-event-in-javascript/ . Also add `EnableEventValidation="false"` in your page which is not mentioned in the link.

Comment: You can do this only by using ajax, if you want it to be dynamic

Comment: The problem with AJAX is, I need to either user a WebMethod or a HTTP Handler, where I cannot access the web page server controls. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: You have added this textbox dynamically with jquery so the option is to use ajax, or you have to handle the change event in client side.

Comment: Does the OnTextChange event fire if you input text manually? ... You could also use an UpdatePanel for roundtrips to the server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361680/asp-net-updatepanel-and-javascript-dopostback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use GetPostBackEventReference and create a js function like this:

```
function Textbox1_OnChange() {
    <%=Page.GetPostBackEventReference(Textbox1, "TextChanged")%>;
}
```

Then you will be able to call this from jQuery after you change the text:

```
 $('#Textbox1').val("TreeView Selected Value");  // your code  
 Textbox1_OnChange(); // new line
```

This will automatically postback the page and invoke your Textbox1_TextChanged server-side event.

Answer (score 0):

- Change Event is only called after your `DOM` gets ready . It cannot be called by dynamically setting values to the textbox . Setting values dynamically and changing values when the `DOM` is ready are different things . The former is not the **change-event** but the latter is .

Why don't you handle all these in **client side** only ? Secondly `on-change` event will only be called when you change the value inside the textbox ( when the `DOM` is ready ) . You are assigning the value to the textbox in the **document-ready** I guess . So it's not a **change event** . Try this :-

```
  $("#TextBox1").on('change',function(){
    //your logic ;    

  });
```

And if you really want to do this from **server side** , then assigning values from the jQuery code will not make that work . As when your `DOM` is ready , the value **Testing** you are assigning is already there . So it's not a **change event** . Try assgning values after your `DOM` gets ready . Your server side **on-change** method will be called for sure .

Hope i am clear to you .

Thanks !!

Comment: I tried onchange of <input> html control, but it didn't work. I have updated the question to understand why I need server script. I am not assigning textbox value when DOM is ready.